# How to disable auto Environment creation from a YAML in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps 2020 on-premise. Working on YAML release pipeline, I figured out that the environments are automatically created if it doesn't exist. Is there a way I could disable the Environment creation from YAML file? I want to do this to avoid misspelling the environment names and restrict non-admins to create Environments.

Answer (score 1):

As this doc: [Create and target an environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#target-an-environment-from-a-deployment-job) stated, `If the specified environment doesn't already exist, an empty environment is created using the environment name provided.`

Thus I am afraid that we cannot disable auto Environment creation from a YAML in Azure DevOps. But this is indeed a good suggestion. I found a similar suggestion ticket in [Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/prevent-automatic-creation-of-new-pipeline-environ/1297857). You can vote and follow this ticket. You can also create a new suggestion ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). The product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.

Comment: Hi Fairoz, Does my answer help? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.